# Swapping OpenGL dll at runtime

Tags: windows, opengl, dll, dynamic-linking

I have an idea for a project which would involve writing a software-based implementation of OpenGL-1.x.

What I'd like to do is take an arbitrary old video game - say, Quake 1 - and replace the system's OpenGL DLL with my own version at runtime.

Every GL function call would then reference my own implementation.

Is this possible? If so, how could I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your .dll in the same directory as the executable (Quake 1) and it should load it before the system one.